# Terraform aws_launch_template user_data variables separation (local and ec2 execution)

Tags: amazon-web-services, variables, terraform, user-data

In my user-data, I have:

```
export INSTANCEID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

And Terraform:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "launch_template" { 
  user_data = base64encode(
      templatefile(
        "${path.module}/user_data/user_data.sh.tpl",
        {
          environment = var.environment
        }
      )
    )
```

In result, I'm getting error:

> Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "INSTANCEID", referenced at ./user_data/user_data.sh.tpl

As we see, INSTANCEID should be set at launch time on EC2 side, but Terraform is trying to substitute this variable on the moment of plan. How can solve it?

Comment: Try adding an additional `$` sign before the first one and check if that will work, i.e., `export INSTANCEID=$$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)`.

Comment: @MarkoE comment is very likely correct answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'll expand to a real answer if it works. :)

Comment: @MattSchuchard sorry for late reply, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Escape that variable in shell script using an extra `$` before it. For example, `INSTANCEID=$${INSTANCEID}`
2. Add that variable as `INSTANCEID = "$INSTANCEID"` under the list of variables for file in terraform script and it will replace `${INSTANCEID}` with `$INSTANCEID` and the script will still work.

Comment: in my example, I set environment variable on EC2 side, so option 2 would not help. but yes, escaping it with $ char solves the issue. thanks

Comment: Option 2 would help as well as it will set its value to `$INSTANCEID` and then `$INSTANCEID` will pick the value from your `export` command as it is actually setting the value. 1st one will solve the issue and is the preferred solution but sometimes you cannot escape it using `$` and you have to use 2nd solution which is actually replacing it with the code instead of value. It is more like a hack. I used it in `while read line` to escape `$line` which was enclosed with escaped double quotes and `$$` didn't work and Terraform still threw error upon `apply`.

Comment: using option 2, do you think `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id` will be executed as user-data on AWS side?

Comment: In your case, if your user-data script only has this one line, `export INSTANCEID=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)` and nothing else then you need to use `INSTANCEID = ""` and the `export` command will update the value when the user data script will execute. In your case, 1st solution is better but if 1st solution doesn't work, we can use the 2nd solution as a workaround.

Comment: No, it has much more lines of course. Does it really matter?

Comment: @RomanNewaza yes because if you are using `INSTANCEID` as `$INSTANCEID` somewhere in the script then that line is causing this error and you need `INSTANCEID = "$INSTANCEID"` instead.